# Messy Rails Model OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to do many `WHERE` in my model collection with `OR` and params on scope.

**This `.where('1=1')` is needed, because then the `OR` does not work.**

My `messy` code looks like this:

```rb
scope :search, ->(params) {
  patients = all.where('1=1') # Please pay attention here!

  if terms = params[:search].presence

    terms.split('|').each do |term|

      patients =  patients.or(
                    Patient.where
                      'name LIKE :like OR ' +
                      'surname_1 LIKE :like OR ' +
                      'surname_2 LIKE :like OR ' +
                      'email LIKE :like OR ' +
                      'identifier_number = :equals OR ' +
                      'history = :equals OR ' +
                      'CAST(telephone_1 AS char) LIKE :like OR ' +
                      'CAST(telephone_2 AS char) LIKE :like ',
                      like:   "%#{ term }%",
                      equals: term)

    end
  end
```

There are a way to avoid this `.where('1=1')` on the line #2?

There are a alternative to do this?

Comment: I'm confused, what is that `1=1` for, again? in a query `WHERE 1=1 OR anything` it doesn't matter what `anything` is, every row will match. Might as well not include the second part. Should work exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`.none`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-none) method, that is a bit cleaner at least than this hack.

> Returns a chainable relation with zero records.
>
> The returned relation implements the Null Object pattern. It is an
>   object with defined null behavior and always returns an empty array of
>   records without querying the database.
>
> Any subsequent condition chained to the returned relation will
>   continue generating an empty relation and will not fire any query to
>   the database.
>
> Used in cases where a method or scope could return zero records but
>   the result needs to be chainable.

```
patients = Patient.none
```

or if you want to return them all if no search params do

```
patients = Patient.all
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
scoped = Patient.where({})
scoped = scoped.or( Patient.where({...}) )
```